What actually is Snapshot in Git?
I've read the document.

Git thinks of its data more like a series of snapshots of a miniature filesystem.

As it says, Git records snapshot when commited in contrast to other VCSs which stores full set of files. What is Snapshot?

The term doesn't have a special meaning here. A snapshot means the capture of a situation at a given time. A portrait is a snapshot of a person. In git it means the recording of the exact state of every file in a given folder. (They didn't feel the need to include the term in the glossary, btw)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_(computer_storage)

git takes a "snapshot" every time you do a command like git add git commit etc. so what its like from gits perspective... okay i have this filesystem. i dont actively keep track of it. but every time a user does some command, i want to sync the changes between the last filesystem i have and the users filesystem

From the docs you linked: "…every time you commit, or save the state of your project, Git basically takes a picture of what all your files look like at that moment…"

Seems to be a difference in data structure. Other tools are described as having a list of files at the outermost layer, and for each file there exist a list of versions. In git the outermost structure is the system snapshots (a.k.a. commits) which have a list of files in the correct version.

Thank you all for posting replys. The question that I meant was "What is the contents of Snapshot". And now I fully understood it is.
The content is copy of the entire code. When making contents, for efficiency, Git does not generate the copy from zero, it only adds files that have changed and the rest of files are just used as previous one.
